# how do you start serverless node server locally?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

How do you start aws-lambda-serverless-node-6 server locally?

What I tried

```
# Followed the quick start instructions at https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/
$ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Redacted/package.json'
$ node server
Error: Cannot find module '/Redacted/server'
```

My ls output

```
$ ls
handler.js      package-lock.json   serverless.yml
```

Comment: You have some missing files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some steps in the tutorials that you skipped.

```
 npm install
```

You don't have the file `package.json` in your working directory. That is why you have the warning:

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Redacted/package.json'

```
node server
```

You want to launch the node server but you don't have the module `server.js` resulting in the error

> Error: Cannot find module '/Redacted/server'.

According the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/), you should first run:

```
npm install -g serverless
```

An then you follow correctly the appropriate steps to create your service or to deploy the server.

Comment: I did all the things you mentioned. Importantly, npm install -g serverless

Comment: @joshsverns, you have to follow all the steps [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/)